P, Q, and G values in a public key
I came across a certificate that contains values $P,Q$, and $G$ besides the public key.
Obviously, $P$ and $Q$ here are primes, but not the two secret primes. I am curious are those values
Public Key Algorithm: dsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (1024 bit)
                pub:
                    56:3f:cd:3b:b0:ef:03:60:2e:43:4e:14:da:e0:db:
                    9c:77:15:f5:ad:78:e2:8a:1f:ff:62:b8:6c:19:60:
                    f0:64:8c:59:ec:88:df:e8:f0:29:e6:6d:d1:27:9e:
                    a9:e5:5a:8d:99:c2:53:27:5f:83:85:d8:b4:7a:93:
                    52:4c:e5:74:da:60:16:f5:95:1a:c9:42:c4:92:d2:
                    44:6b:73:45:dd:62:87:43:d4:00:02:81:4b:27:1f:
                    69:ac:c1:57:70:20:97:da:5f:01:c0:dc:7a:e7:93:
                    04:12:51:dd:e2:c5:be:37:13:a2:0c:12:98:64:1f:
                    e4:c6:0f:ec:a2:5a:9a:43
                P:
                    00:fd:7f:53:81:1d:75:12:29:52:df:4a:9c:2e:ec:
                    e4:e7:f6:11:b7:52:3c:ef:44:00:c3:1e:3f:80:b6:
                    51:26:69:45:5d:40:22:51:fb:59:3d:8d:58:fa:bf:
                    c5:f5:ba:30:f6:cb:9b:55:6c:d7:81:3b:80:1d:34:
                    6f:f2:66:60:b7:6b:99:50:a5:a4:9f:9f:e8:04:7b:
                    10:22:c2:4f:bb:a9:d7:fe:b7:c6:1b:f8:3b:57:e7:
                    c6:a8:a6:15:0f:04:fb:83:f6:d3:c5:1e:c3:02:35:
                    54:13:5a:16:91:32:f6:75:f3:ae:2b:61:d7:2a:ef:
                    f2:22:03:19:9d:d1:48:01:c7
                Q:
                    00:97:60:50:8f:15:23:0b:cc:b2:92:b9:82:a2:eb:
                    84:0b:f0:58:1c:f5
                G:
                    00:f7:e1:a0:85:d6:9b:3d:de:cb:bc:ab:5c:36:b8:
                    57:b9:79:94:af:bb:fa:3a:ea:82:f9:57:4c:0b:3d:
                    07:82:67:51:59:57:8e:ba:d4:59:4f:e6:71:07:10:
                    81:80:b4:49:16:71:23:e8:4c:28:16:13:b7:cf:09:
                    32:8c:c8:a6:e1:3c:16:7a:8b:54:7c:8d:28:e0:a3:
                    ae:1e:2b:b3:a6:75:91:6e:a3:7f:0b:fa:21:35:62:
                    f1:fb:62:7a:01:24:3b:cc:a4:f1:be:a8:51:90:89:
                    a8:83:df:e1:5a:e5:9f:06:92:8b:66:5e:80:7b:55:
                    25:64:01:4c:3b:fe:cf:49:2a


It is the DSA where $(p,q,g)$ are public values. It is defined in  FIPS 186-4 but not defined in FIPS 186-5.
The $p$ and $q$ primes of lengths, respectively;

L = 1024, N = 160
L = 2048, N = 224
L = 2048, N = 256
L = 3072, N = 256

and

$p-1$ must be multiple of $q$

with a random $h \in \{2,\ldots,p-2 \}$ chose $g = h^{(p-1)/q} \bmod p$. if $g = 1$ then choose another random $h$.



The tuple, (p, q, g) are the finite field group parameters in DSA, which are equivalent to the elliptic curve parameters in ECDSA.

If you  look above you'll see DSA, which is a signature algorithm, meaning you get to sign using the private key, hence to verify the digest according to RFC 3279 you should be able to use a public modulus for that purpose in a X.509 CRls infrastructure, therefore you have the public keys displayed to allow you to do so.
